# PySpark read multiple txt files as json format from a directory

Tags: python, json, pyspark, k-means, azure-databricks

I am currently doing a task in distributed databases classes for reading txt files of tweet data written as json file format and load the tweets into a dataframe (and later run them through pyspark's kmeans algorith). 
I have the directory however i dont know the names of the specific text file (i am pretty sure all the files in the directory are relevant text files to the task).

In addition because I am supposed to run it through a kmeans algorithm, how do i get the non numeral features to be used in the run?

Any assitance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some more digging seems like

```
dataset = spark.read.format("json").load("/mnt/ddscoursedatabricksstg/ddscoursedatabricksdata/coronavirus-tweets/*txt")
```

Seems to do the trick.